# Identical google maps code works on one page and not another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I am working with Rails and the Gmaps4rails gem. I have added a map on two actions in my controller. This is the code for both.

```
def index
@clubs = policy_scope(Club)
@date = params[:date] || Date.today

@hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@clubs) do |club, marker|
  marker.lat club.latitude
  marker.lng club.longitude
  # marker.infowindow render_to_string(partial: "/clubs/map_box", locals: { club: club })
end
end

def show_map
@club = Club.find(params[:id])
authorize @club

@hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@club) do |club, marker|
  marker.lat club.latitude
  marker.lng club.longitude
  # marker.infowindow render_to_string(partial: "/clubs/map_box", locals: { club: club })
end
end
```

This is my view code which is added to both pages with a partial.

```
<div id="map" style="width: 50%; height: 400px;"></div>

<% content_for(:after_js) do %>
<%= javascript_tag do %>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
  handler.buildMap({ internal: { id: 'map' } }, function() {
    markers = handler.addMarkers(<%= raw @hash.to_json %>);
    handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
    handler.fitMapToBounds();
    if (markers.length == 0) {
      handler.getMap().setZoom(2);
    } else if (markers.length == 1) {
      handler.getMap().setZoom(14);
    }
  });
});
```

The problem is that the map is appearing on my index page, but not on my show_map page. The idea is to have the show_map show the map with the marker for just one club. However the weird thing is that it doesn't matter what I do, I can't get the map on show_map to appear.

Even if I have the EXACT SAME code in the index method and the show_map method (I tried to make both methods identical to see whether it will work), it still doesn't work in the show_map view.

I am getting this error in the show_map view page: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined.

Has anyone ever encountered this same problem?

Comment: Well, its not the exact same code, `@clubs` and `@club` are different. Have you tested the value of `@club`?

Comment: Yes, I meant that even when I tried with the exact same code in both methods it still wasn't working. I tested the value of the @hash at the end of both methods and both are exactly the same, because I only have one club in my test database.

Comment: @TeodorMavrodiev: well, if everything is the same, then it should work. _Something_ differs. You need to find out what. Or prepare a [mcve] and we may take a look.

Comment: Also, are there errors in browser console on show page?

Comment: Yes, I am getting this error in the show_map view page: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined. You are probably right that something is different, but I am just using a partial for both pages, the view code is exactly similar, and even when I have the same code in both methods it still creates the same problem. Do you have any ideas what else could be different?

Comment: @TeodorMavrodiev: yes, I think that `@hash` on those two pages is not exactly the same, contrary to what you assert.

Comment: I raised at the end of both methods and this is the result in both cases for @hash.
 [{:lat=>42.6483675, :lng=>23.3425648}]

Comment: I even tried to get the @hash.to_json value and paste that directly in the view code and it still breaks in only the view for show_map and works in the other one.

Comment: @TeodorMavrodiev: ok, I'm afraid this is where we need the [mcve]. By that I mean a super stripped-down rails app, with just those two pages, necessary migrations and seed data. So that we can clone, migrate, run and see the problem. And btw, if you want other users to see your comments, you `@mention` them.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks, I haven't used StackOverflow a lot I didn't know about the mention. I don't think I can add any more details short of posting my whole project here. If you want to check out the github, it is here https://github.com/teodormavrodiev/club_reservation/tree/add-geocoding. Thanks for trying to help anyway.

Comment: @TeodorMavrodiev: that's the thing, you don't need to post your __whole__ project. The magic of MCVE is that when you prepare it, you cut off irrelevant parts. Cut without mercy. If the problem still persists, then you __know__ the code you just removed doesn't affect/cause the problem. And when you distill the code down to the bare minimum, just enough to reproduce the problem, it is very likely that you'll just __see__ what causes the problem (and find the answer yourself). Happens to me all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to give an array to this function:

```
Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@club)
```

Try that:

```
Gmaps4rails.build_markers([@club])
```

To show_map action

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is having this same problem, I ended up moving on and leaving it for later. I added the API keys to push to production, and somehow, once I did that, the Google Maps started working on every page, not just the index. Hope this helps.

Comment: "Hope this helps." - this answer is unlikely to help anyone :) But good that it finally works for you, as it should.